# Recurring event based on day of the year

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Today is the [Day of the Programmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_the_Programmer). It's set to be on the 256th day of the year.

Is there a way of creating recurring events in Outlook based on the day of the year? I haven't found a way to do so. Keep in mind that there are leap years, making dates jump (the 256th day being September 12th during leap years, September 13th otherwise).

Comment: No, I'm afraid there is no way for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Outlooks's recurrence feature doesn't work like that. You can do recurrence based on the *nth* day of the month (to an extent) but not the *nth* day of the year.

The closest you could come would be to set up a recurring event on 9/13 every 4 years, starting on the next leap year, then also set up a new event (the same content; just a new event item) to recur on 9/12 annually. Then, on leap years, set yourself a reminder to cancel that year's annual 9/12 occurrence.

In effect, that would give you the Sept. 13th event every four years, and the Sept. 12th event all other years, with a tiny bit of interaction required.

Comment: Okay, I guess that's as good as it will get. It's a pretty fringe case anyways. Thanks!